# How to convert a JSON file into class POJO complet using java?

Tags: java, json

How to convert file JSON to class POJO complet using Java?

I tried with Jackson API but the result is `arrayList` and I want a `class complet` like:

```java
class test {
    public int age ;
    public string name ;
}
```

This is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] a) 
{ 
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Staff value = null;
    try {
        value = mapper.readValue(new File("C://staff.json"), Staff.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    System.out.println(value);                  
}
```

Staff is a normal class with fields and getters setters.

I want to display the class complet when I enter file json, not display array.

Comment: Could you please give us the input JSON, the Staff class and what is printed by your println() call ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: @ThomasMartin this is json File
{
    "name": "mkyong",
    "age": 38,
    "position": [
        "Founder",
        "CTO",
        "Writer"
    ],
    "skills": [
        "java",
        "python",
        "node",
        "kotlin"
    ],
    "salary": {
        "2018": 14000,
        "2012": 12000,
        "2010": 10000
    }
}
and my println
Staff[name=mkyong,age=38,position=[Founder, CTO, Writer],skills=[java, python, node, kotlin],salary={2018=14000, 2012=12000, 2010=10000}]
thank's again

Comment: The println is simply printing what you have in a toString() method in Staff class. The values are correctly read from JSON, as per your comments. Please check that method and modify based on your requirements. When you say "I want to display the class complet", what is it that you want to display?

Comment: @MRTJ yes i know the response is correctly , i mean i want to generate dynamically the class POJO like 
public class X {
public string name ;

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? What's the point ? Besides, Java is a statically-typed language, so it's not possible by design.